# Error handling mechanism for plugin javascripts

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I have created a javascript plugin, which different third parties will use in their websites.
My plugin has a dependency on a modeldata object, and its the third party's responsibility to make this model data available on their pages to the plugin.

In my plugin JS I have done this in the very beginning -

```
(function() {
    if (!modelData) {
                throw new Error("Please assign model data");
            }

---------------some more code -------------

}();
```

I don't have any catch, because there is no meaningful handling it.

Is handling it in this manner correct?

Will it break any other JS execution on the end site?

Is there any alternate better solution?

Answer (score 0):

If the user of your function is passing in `modelData` then it's completely reasonable to throw an error or to even try and use it and let and undefined error happen.

I think you'll need to expand your question if you want more specific advice then that.